# mouse drag seems to be offset when i make my game responsive

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, html5-canvas, mouseevent

I am making a very simple site which is mainly a JavaScript mobile game.  The game involves dragging a character left and right.  Before I make my game responsive, the mouse drag works fine and perfect (the character move followed the dragging) but the moment I applied responsiveness, the mouse drag seems to be offset which my character does not follow the finger accurately.

Note: the mouse event is bound to canvas, responsive also to canvas

Comment: Please share the code you're using + fiddle.

Comment: If "responsive" means you're resizing the canvas, be sure you're resizing the canvas element (e.g., canvas.width=100) rather than resizing with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but perhaps You could get the width/height of the current mobile device, then set it to the css?

Comment: already did those. use the @media right? but still the same effect

Comment: Perhaps follow this: 1. on load (before anything else) use js to get/set content sizes 2. load html/create canvas. 3. initialize the game. This way the canvas is drawn to the resolution, not drawn base sizing, then modified after (avoiding "Cascading")